# Hotmail incorrectly "stretching" HTML/CSS signature

Tags: html, css, email, hotmail

I've been working on making a signature (CSS+HTML) work across multiple platforms, and have hit the wall when it comes to Hotmail.
For some reason, when sending this signature to my Hotmail address, it gets stretched vertically. It seems that Hotmail, for one reason or another, is adding a lot of white space below the text in each table cell?

The problem is clearly illustrated in this graphic: http://www.madculture.es/images/test.jpg
The first signature there, is the intended output. I added borders on #2, to better highlight the problem. Signature three is how it looks when received in Hotmail! :(

This signature works fine in Outlook 2003-2013, Gmail, Lotus Notes, but not in Hotmail.

Does anyone know what could be the reason? I'm clueless, having experimented with this for days now.

Here's the full code for the signature:

```
<div>
 <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" height="50" style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 1em;">
  <tr>
   <td rowspan="4">
    <img src="mc2.png" nosend="1" width="170" height="86" />
   </td>
   <td style="padding-top: 2px;">
    John D. Doe
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="font-size: 0.85em; font-weight: bold; color: #932D1F; padding-bottom: 2px;">
    Marketing & analytics
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="display: block;">
    <a href="mailto:johnd@doe.com" style="color: #666; text-decoration: none; font-size: 0.9em;">johnd@doe.com</a>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="font-size: 1.05em; font-weight: bold; color: #444; padding-top: 1px;">
    Madrid
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

I hope someone can help...

Answer (score 0):

Try slowly removing elements and re-testing at every stage. As a start:

- Your table has a height set that's less than your main image
- Use nested tables, not `rowspan` for better email client support
- Avoid `padding` and use set heights instead
- Don't set your `td` to `display: block`
- Add font styling directly to `td` s (not the `table`) to get Outlook working correctly

Comment: How did email clients get so badly out of step with browsers? it makes me want to weep inside when I read a recommendation to use nested tables for layout in 2013.  :-(

Comment: Thanks for your replies.
I tried all your suggestions, but to no avail.
Having kept stripping down the signature, I ended up with:
<div><table><tr><td>John D. Doe</td></tr><tr><td>Marketing & analytics</td></tr></table></div>
- and the problem is STILL there.... I can't wrap my head around this :(

Comment: Can you stick the entirety of your HTML email into jsFiddle or similar? Sounds like some other CSS or HTML element is having an effect somehow.

Comment: @Spudley tell me about it. In my last job I spent 2 years creating HTML emails all day, and a little part of me died each time I had to resort to a `font` tag :(

Comment: @CherryFlavourPez How can I go about doing this? If I 'view source' on the received e-mail in Outlook, there will be a lot of extra added MS-styles in the code (but this doesn't matter, as the signature works fine in Outlook).
If I do "view source" in Hotmail, on the received message, well there's a huge mountain of code, I can't even find the text from my signature in there for some reason.

Comment: Send me a test at: ed_melly[at]hotmail.com, I'll take a look.